# how to calculate how many times is changed in the column

Tags: pandas

how I can calculate on the most easy way, how much values changes I have in the specific DataFrame columns. For example I have follow DF:

```
a b
0 1
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 1
5 2
6 2
7 3
8 3
9 3
```

In this Data Frame the values in the column `b` have been changed 4 times (in the rows 4,5,6 and 8).

My very simple solution is:

```
a = 0
for i in range(df.shape[0] - 1):
   if df['b'].iloc[i] != df['b'].iloc[i+1]:
       a+=1
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your solution?

Comment: @Rafalon, I search for best solution with pandas function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `index`:

```
idx = df.index[df['b'].diff().shift().fillna(0).ne(0)]
print (idx)
Int64Index([4, 5, 6, 8], dtype='int64')
```

For more general solution is possible indexing by `arange`:

```
a = np.arange(len(df))[df['b'].diff().shift().bfill().ne(0)].tolist()
print (a)
[4, 5, 6, 8]
```

**Explanation**:

First get difference by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
print (df['b'].diff())
0    NaN
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    1.0
4   -1.0
5    1.0
6    0.0
7    1.0
8    0.0
9    0.0
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

Then [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) by one value:

```
print (df['b'].diff().shift())
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    1.0
5   -1.0
6    1.0
7    0.0
8    1.0
9    0.0
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

Replace first `NaN`s by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
print (df['b'].diff().shift().fillna(0))
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    1.0
5   -1.0
6    1.0
7    0.0
8    1.0
9    0.0
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

And compare for not equal to `0`

```
print (df['b'].diff().shift().fillna(0).ne(0))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8     True
9    False
Name: b, dtype: bool
```

Comment: @user495490 - Please check answer, but original was modified - `.bfill()` was changed to `fillna(0)`

Comment: yes, I have checked. Thank you very much! Unfortunately I can not get you some points, because I someself don't have enough reputation for this...

Comment: Only one additional question, it doesnt work, if I have a string instead of numeric values... What I have to use instead of diff?

Comment: Then need first `df['b'] = pd.factorize(df['b'])[0]`

Answer (score 0):

If the `a` is a column and not the index:

```
 idx = df['a'].loc[df['b'].diff().shift().fillna(0) != 0]
```